# Why am I receiving this Error: Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (task1) in ESP32 using a FreeRTOS program?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I'm getting this error by running a FreeRTOS program on my ESP32 using arduino ide, I don't understand why this happens because this same program works on an arduino Uno with no errors:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception). 
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (task1) 
Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x40088a4f  PS      : 0x00060636  A0      : 0x800d3155  A1      : 0x3ffb9130  
A2      : 0x3ffb8eb4  A3      : 0xffffffff  A4      : 0x00060620  A5      : 0x00060623  
A6      : 0x00060623  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x00000001  A9      : 0x00000000  
A10     : 0x00060623  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x007bee88  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x00000000  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
//#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
//Overload happens if xTaskGetTickCount – lastTickCount (the first parm to vTaskDelayUntil) is >= period in ticks

void task1(void *pvParameters);
void task2(void *pvParameters);
void task3(void *pvParameters);

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Create tasks
//xTaskCreate(Task function, Task name, , Task parameter, Task priority, ); 
  Serial.println("111111");   
  xTaskCreate(task1, "task1", 512, NULL, 1, NULL);
  Serial.println("222222");
  xTaskCreate(task2, "task2", 512, NULL, 2, NULL);
  xTaskCreate(task3, "task3", 512, NULL, 3, NULL);
  //vTaskStartScheduler();

}

void loop() {}

void task1(void *pvParameters) {

  (void) pvParameters;
  TickType_t waketime, period = 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

  waketime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  while(1){

    Serial.println('M'); //This happens almost immediately, so we need to add an artificial delay, a  to simulate a task running for a few ms, it only serves as a notification that the task started
    vTaskDelay(10);
    if(xTaskGetTickCount() - waketime >= period) 
      Serial.println("Overload in task 1");

    vTaskDelayUntil(&waketime, period);
  
  }

}

void task2(void *pvParameters) {

  (void) pvParameters;
  TickType_t waketime, period = 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

  waketime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  while(1) {

    Serial.println('E'); //This happens almost immediately, so we need to add an artificial delay, a  to simulate a task running for a few ms, it only serves as a notification that the task started
    vTaskDelay(10);
    if(xTaskGetTickCount() - waketime >= period) Serial.println("Overload in task 2");
    vTaskDelayUntil(&waketime, period);
  
  }

}

void task3(void *pvParameters) {

  (void) pvParameters;
  TickType_t waketime, period = 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

  waketime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  while(1) {

    Serial.println('S'); //This happens almost immediately, so we need to add an artificial delay, a  to simulate a task running for a few ms, it only serves as a notification that the task started
    vTaskDelay(10);
    if(xTaskGetTickCount() - waketime >= period) Serial.println("Overload in task 3");
    vTaskDelayUntil(&waketime, period);
  
  }

}
```

I tried increasing the task stack memory in xtaskcreate and the same error occurs, although when I increased it to 1024 nothing shows up in the serial monitor. This same program works flawlessly on arduino uno and raspberry pi pico. I also tried changing the tasks' period and their execution time, which is the delay, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> although when I increased it to 1024 nothing shows up in the serial monitor.

Doing nothing to your code except using 4096 for stack size causes it to print things on serial.

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
load:0x40078000,len:13864
load:0x40080400,len:3608
entry 0x400805f0
111111
222222M

E
S
S
E
M
S
ME
```

I won't tell you that it's correct, but it seems fairly clear that you haven't given it enough stack to work with.

With my current setup

```cpp
Serial.println(configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE);
```

is printing 828. I don't know how exactly how to interpret that number. But unless I found otherwise, I could default to considering it the requirement to start a task that uses no stack of it own (no local variables, no calling). The memories of the esp32 seem large enough that no matter how you're using them it doesn't make sense to go so minimal for a handful to tasks. I chose 4096 somewhat arbitrarily. I'm not suggesting is a good value.